# python - return dict object with str as key and no.of times it occurs as value

Tags: python

The `get_last_three_letters_dict()` function which is passed a
string of text as a parameter. The function first converts the parameter
string to lower case and then returns a dictionary object which has:

- the `remove_less_than_2` code removes any pairs in the resulting dictionary where
  the last three letters occur just the once in the parameter string of text.
- keys which are the last three letters of any words in the parameter
  string of text with length greater than 2 and
- corresponding values which are the number of words in the parameter
  string of text which end with these last three letters.

I have this so far:

```
sentence = 'west best worst first tapping snapping in a pest the straining singing forest living'

def remove_less_than_2(a_dict):

    all_keys = list(a_dict.keys())
    for key in all_keys:
      if a_dict[key] == 1:
         del a_dict[key]

def get_last_three_letters_dict(sentence):

    new_dict = {}

    new_sentence = sentence.lower()
    new_sentence = sentence.split()
    for word in new_sentence:
        if len(word) > 2:
            new_dict[word[-3:]] = sentence.count(word[-3:])
    return new_dict
```

But it returns some values more than it should.

```
est : 4
ing : 6
rst : 2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
sentence = ' "west best worst first tapping snapping in a pest the straining singing forest living'

# Get the last 3 letters of each word if its length is greater than 3
words_gt3 = [word[-3:] for word in sentence.split() if len(word) >= 3]

# Count them (you can use collections.Counter() too)
out = {}
for w in words_gt3:
    if w not in out.keys():
        out[w] = 0
    out[w] += 1

# Filter non repeated words
out = dict([e for e in out.items() if e[1] > 1])
print out
# {'rst': 2, 'est': 4, 'ing': 5}
```

> What am I doing wrong?

`sentence.count()`: counts the number of occurrences in the entire string (not in each word).
So `'singing'.count('ing')` will return `2`. that's why you counted `6` `ing` rather than `5`.

Comment: You are not filtering non-repeated words as he asked. A straight forward dict comprehension should do it.

Comment: I would still use a `Counter` to avoid the loop as I suggested in my answer but your answer is also right

Comment: List comprehensions and loops are still faster than `Counter`, but you're free to use what you want.

Comment: I still use list comprehensions and dict comprehensions. The speed difference for this kind of application is completely negligible. If you get to the point where you have to optimize a Python script to use for loops instead of a container from the standard library you should probably consider refactoring your code or even switching to a compiled language.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve in easily doable with dict/list comprehensions and Counters:

```
from collections import Counter

sentence = ' "west best worst first tapping snapping in a pest the straining singing forest living'

filtered_counter = {k: v for k, v in Counter([word[-3:] for word in sentence.lower().split() if len(word) > 2]).items() if v > 1}
```

First we import the `Counter` type from the standard library and we define `sentence`. The next line is creating an array with the last 3 letters of every word after lowering the full sentence and checking if the length of the word is at least 3; it is creating a Counter object from it, what yields a `dict`-like object that enumerates how many times an element was found in the array; then a dict comprehension is used to filter the output so that it doesn't include non-repeated words.

I will decompose this one-liner so that you can see it better:

```
lowered_sentence = sentence.lower()
words = lowered_sentence.split()
filtered_words = [word for word in words if len(word) > 2]
# filtered_words = filter(lambda x: len(x) > 2, words)
word_ends = [word[-3:] for word in filtered_words]
counter = Counter(word_ends)
filtered_counter = {key: value for key, value in counter.items() if value > 1}
```